# Server backup solutions

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

Who are some good linux server backup solutions that support rsync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally prefer a package called Duplicity.

http://duplicity.nongnu.org/

There are various packages and services that support rsync.

http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/
http://code.google.com/p/rsync-backup/
http://www.s3rsync.com/
http://www.bqbackup.com/
http://www.rsync.net/

We could use some more information about your question. Are you looking for local backup? A service? A few machines, or many? How often will backups run? Are they full or incremental?

Comment: Yeah, need more info from OP. For example, rsnapshot (rsnapshot.org) is a great local backup tool that uses rsync and supports snapshots via hard links.